# how add some textbox values in session in jsp page after click a button except form submit?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, session

i have 5 textboxes and a buttom in my page.i want add these textboxes values in my session without form submitting.whats the problem in my code?

```
   <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>$Title$</title>
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#button').click(function() {
    var val1 = $('#text1').val();
    var val2 = $('#text2').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'add.jsp',
      data: { text1: val1, text2: val2 },
      success: function(response) {
        $('#result').html(response);
      }
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="register.do" method="post">
<br>
<label>name</label>
<input type="text" name="txt1" id="text1">
<br>
<label>family</label>
<input type="text" name="family" id="text2">
<br>
<label>article name</label>
<input type="text" name="uni">
<br>
<label>article place</label>
<input type="text" name="uniname">
<br>
<label>article grade</label>
<input type="text" name="unigrade">
<br>
<label>article date</label>
<input type="text" name="unitype">
<input type="button" name="button" id="button">
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

i dont recive any parameter in my add.jsp page to store in session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#button').click` is prematurely registered, not even the DOM elements are completely loaded, that's why it's not triggered.
Move your code inside as follows:

```
$(function(){ //  hold till DOM becomes safe to manipulate.
    Put your code here.  
});
```